# How should I use "eponym", "eponymous" and "namesake"?

Tags: word-choice

I was in London and visited the Tower Bridge. Afterwards, I went to a pub called The Tower Bridge. Just to be clear, the pub is named after the bridge.

Which of the following are correct?

1. The bridge is the **eponym** of the pub.
2. The pub is the **eponym** of the bridge.
3. From the pub, I could see the **eponymous** bridge.
4. After I saw the bridge, I went to the **eponymous** pub.
5. The bridge is the **namesake** of the pub.
6. The pub is the **namesake** of the bridge.

Comment: I avoid all of these and say (or write) things like *Oh, is the pub named after the Tower Bridge?* or *Yes, she's named after her grandmother.* I can't ever remember how eponyms are supposed to work!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a couple of entries in the New York Times "After Deadline" column useful.

The [first](http://topics.blogs.nytimes.com/2011/07/19/eponymous-sources/):

> In precise, traditional usage, an “eponym” is someone or something
>   that gives its name to something else. So “eponymous” describes the
>   giver of the name, NOT the receiver. A restaurateur named Joe Smith
>   could be described as the eponymous owner of Joe Smith’s Restaurant,
>   but the establishment is not “Mr. Smith’s eponymous restaurant.”
>
> (The opposite problem often occurs with “namesake.” That word properly
>   describes the receiver of the name — a grandchild may be the namesake
>   of her grandmother, but not the other way around.)

So the only ones of your examples that have the correct use of “eponymous” are those that describe the giver (the bridge) and not the receiver. And conversely, only in #6 is “namesake” used correctly.

The [second entry](http://topics.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/09/14/words-we-love-too-much-5/) is more pertinent to the use of “eponymous:”

> Sometimes I quibble over words we overuse. Sometimes I complain about
>   words that are misused. And sometimes I take issue with words that
>   seem pretentious or contrived.
>
> Then there’s “eponymous,” which could fit any of those categories.
>
> In precise use, an eponym is someone who gives a name to something
>   else, and “eponymous” describes the source of the name, not the
>   receiver.
>
> More often than not, we and others muddle this distinction. And often,
>   there’s a way to say what we mean without using “eponymous” at all. *So
>   let’s use it sparingly, and wisely.*

Hear, hear.

Edit: For reference, the entry for *[eponym](http://wordsmith.org/words/eponym.html)* from Wordsmith.org, one of my favorite resources:

> **eponym** (EP-uh-nim) *noun*
>
> 1. A person, real or imaginary, from whom something, as a tribe, nation, or place, takes or is said to take its name.
> 2. A word based on or derived from a person's name.
> 3. Any ancient official whose name was used to designate his year of office.

Comment: +1 for *namesake* only being suitable for the *receiver* of the name (I parse it as "named for the sake of"), but I can't accept your columnist's opinions on "correct" use of *eponym/eponymous*.

Comment: "Can't accept?" Why not? M-W defines _eponym_ as _name giver_...

Comment: Bad choice of words - I'm not an authority on the matter, so it's not really up to me to argue with dictionaries. What I meant was that some of the usages that are acceptable to that columnist will probably always grate on my ear, and I'm unlikely to start using them myself.

Comment: Thinking about it some more, I think I *am* prepared to take issue with that columnist. According to his antiquated pedantic rules, I have no grammatical term to describe words like *sandwich, hoover, jeep, biro, etc.*, which is frankly ridiculous. I think nearly everyone acquainted with the word **eponym** would say that's what these are called.

Comment: See sense #2 in my edit. #1 is the sense used by "After Deadline" and so the most common usage (although apparently not in your experience).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Nobody knows how the word "jeep" originated.   But there is already a term for words like "hoover" and "biro" -- "Britishism".  :)

Answer (score 7):

Personally, I'm only comfortable with (3) and (4). In this context I don't think it's important which was named first, but I *would* think it odd if, say, someone reviewing the album *Peter Gabriel* were to mention the *eponymous singer*. So far as I'm concerned, such "untitled" albums are always called *the eponymous album [by so-and-so]*.

I see some people claim that *eponymous* should only be applied to the *original, source* named person or thing, not something subsequently named after him/it. In the spirit of Samuel Johnson's ["I refute it *thus*"](http://www.samueljohnson.com/refutati.html), my metaphorical kick at such pedantry is [89 written instances](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22the%20eponymous%22&oq=%22the%20eponymous%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=4449285l4454855l16l4455763l15l15l0l0l0l0l158l906l14.1l15l0&gs_l=serp.3...4449285l4454855l16l4455763l15l15l0l0l0l0l158l906l14j1l15l0&pbx=1&biw=1264&bih=859&cad=cbv&sei=pV5dT6CAPYWY8QO4ufHvDg#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22eponymous%20taxa%22&oq=%22eponymous%20taxa%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=5235l9642l0l10192l9l9l0l0l0l0l175l617l7.2l9l0&gs_l=serp.3...5235l9642l0l10193l9l9l0l0l0l0l175l617l7j2l9l0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=13e2384ef21332d9&biw=1264&bih=859) of "eponymous taxa" (where "taxa" is the plural of [taxon](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/taxa) - *a taxonomic category, as a species or genus*). Almost all those instances will be from educated academics, and obviously they're talking about *categories named after the person who first identified them*, not the people themselves.

For good measure, here's an [eponymous pub](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dCBGBt7a0DoC&pg=PA232&dq=%22eponymous%20pub%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DmZdT6nxMY2E8gPG_cHfDw&ved=0CFUQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22eponymous%20pub%22&f=false), *The Crooked Billet*, which gives its name to a group of nearby houses called *Crooked Billet*. I see no reason why either the giver or receiver of a name must be an actual person in order for *eponymous* to be validly used.

But for me at least, only *words* can be "eponyms", and only *people* can be "namesakes".

Comment: I didn't bother checking - just wrote what came to mind. Which is why I was careful to say *personally*, and *for me at least*. But I'll probably continue to make those distinctions even if someone finds a dictionary that disagrees with them.

Answer (score 3):

Correct examples:

> Berkeley is a city on the east shore of San Francisco Bay in northern Alameda County, California that is the **namesake** of eighteenth-century bishop and philosopher George Berkeley.
>
> Eighteenth-century bishop and philosopher George Berkeley is the **eponym** of the city of Berkeley, California.

They cannot be used interchangeably. Namesake indicates a place, thing or person named *after* someone, something or someplace. Epoynm specifies a place, thing or person that something, someone or someplace is named *after*.

I am a professional copy writer and hold a degree in Journalism.

Comment: It seems like in modern usage "eponymous" is more often than not used in direct opposition to its original meaning.

Answer (score 1):

None of these seem to be proper, given that eponym and eponymous are used for people or things that are named after a person.  Since the Tower Bridge is not a person, these terms should not be used.  (The Tower Bridge is, of course, itself named after the Tower of London, but its name is not an eponym either, since the Tower is not a person.)

Comment: Well, towers aren't often eponymous, so I didn't expect to find any references. Apparently [hotels can be](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22eponymous%20hotel%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en), and they're sometimes eponymous to a place rather than a person.

Answer (score 0):

I believe examples 1,3 and 6 to be correct. According to Webster's:

Eponymous | Definition of Eponymous by Merriam-Webster
www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eponymous
Merriam‑Webster
Definition of eponymous. : of, relating to, or being the person or thing for whom or which something is named : of, relating to, or being an eponym.

Therefore, what brought me here was trying to think of the word for my eponymous great great grandfather for whom I am named.