# A word that means "to become one's name"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word which indicates that a person has adopted a quality suggested by their name, e.g. a person named Grace who is indeed graceful, or perhaps someone named Shepherd who has become a shepherd.

I have a strong notion that I once learned such a word, but I have forgotten it and have never re-discovered it.

Comment: You're probably thinking of [eponymous](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/49281/2637). Some people carp about how it *should* be used, but if you said *"I'd like you to meet my eponymous wife Grace"*, it would be understood that you think your wife is "graceful" or "full of grace".

Comment: For a multiple-word phrase, try _true to one's name_. Oddly I cannot find a good English-only reference, only translations, which suggests that it's a concept that's less common in English than in other cultures.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, if someone said that to me I wouldn't understand it like that at all. My first instinct would be to interpret that as meaning Grace is somehow named after the speaker. To convey what you mean I would say something like *my wife Grace, who lives up to her name*.

Comment: @dbmag9: I'm not saying it would be a "correct" usage of *eponymous*, according to strict grammar/definitions. But OP said he was looking for a "word", and so far *eponymous* seems to be the only contender. Your rewording is perfectly valid English, but doesn't meet OP's specification. Some people might say **aptly-named** counts as a "hyphenated word", but I think that's really just hitting below the belt.

Comment: I understood that, and wasn't offering the phrase as an answer to the OP's question. Rather I was commenting that, while *eponymous* is indeed a word, I wouldn't understand it as meaning what you've used it to mean. It may well be the single word with the closest meaning to what the OP wants, but I don't think it's sufficiently close to meet the OP's specification, as you put it.

Comment: It is not a single word, but the New Scientist's _Feedback_ section has had a long-running editorial column centered on examples of this phenomenon, which they call _nominative determinism_.

Comment: A common idiom in Britain is to say something like 'We have a new nurse in the practice, Jane Lovely - ***Lovely by name and lovely by nature***'. It is always said like this even if the name does not actually refer to someone's nature. E.g Let's say a new employee joins the firm with the surname *Chubb* , and it so happens that they are slightly on the heavy side. Almost certainly some wag is bound to remark, out of their earshot, *Chubb by name and chubb by nature*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Aptronym

> An aptronym, aptonym, or euonym is a personal name aptly or peculiarly suited to its owner.
> [[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptronym)]

Comment: Interesting, this isn't _exactly_ what I had in mind but seems a good enough fit.  There are some very amusing examples on the linked Wikipedia article.  I fear I may have invented the memory I describe in my question, I was sure there was some word to describe the _process_ of becoming your name, whereas 'aptronym' describes the name itself... I fear it was an illusion, and 'aptronym' is a lovely enough word for you to have taught me!

Comment: Hi Wool -- I completely understand the distinction you are making of "becoming" as it were an aptronym - I don't think there is a SW for that.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you may be thinking of [Nominative determinism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_determinism), a theory which describes a phenomenon where somebody's name significantly influences their job, status or personality.

Comment: Was there really a _Cardinal Sin_!?